# Rails internationalization (i18n): Everything translating except layouts/application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

I keep getting "translation missing: en.layouts.application.title"
for title or any item I try to translate within app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file.

**config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:

  layouts:
    application:
      title:  "My Catalog"
      home:  "Home"
      store:   "Store"
      faq:      "FAQ"
      contact:  "Contact"
      about:    "About"
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<div id="banner">
  <% t('.title') %>
</div>
<div id="nav_menu" class="sidebar_menu">
  <a href="/"><%= t('.home') %></a>
  <a href="/store"><%= t('.store') %></a>
  <a href="/faq"><%= t('.faq') %></a>
  <a href="/contact"><%= t('.contact') %></a>
  <a href="/about"><%= t('.about') %></a>
</div>
```

All the translations in the views are working but anything in the layout says its missing.
I am using en.yml, fr.yml, and es.yml and it's the same issue with each (fr.layouts.application.title and es.layouts.application.title, respectively)

If I move the lines out of the layouts: application: nest and into the root hierarchy of the .yml file (removing the period from the t method of course) then everything translates. 
As soon as I move them back under layouts: application: I get translation missing again.

What could be wrong?
I am using Rails 3.2.7

EDIT 1: Just tried using <% t('layouts.application.title') %> but still says translation missing.

EDIT 2: Work-around found if I copy or rename application.html.erb to a different name (and change *.yml files accordingly).
If I start a **new project** translations work just fine within application.html.erb.
However in the ***current project***: as long as I'm using application.html.erb (even with minimal test content) I still get translation missing.

Comment: Can you clarify that you still get a missing translation error when you leave the translations in the nested hierarchy (don't move them to the root hierarchy) and use the full lookup instead of the lazy lookup in the views ie `t('layouts.application.title')`?

Comment: Thanks for replying. It's still giving me translation missing. Updated original post.

Comment: Strange...are you using Spork? If so, have you restarted it to make sure it reloads in your changes made under the **locales** directory?

Comment: Yup. Restarted webrick after each change to confirm.

Comment: No. I'm not using Spork. Above comment was answering second question.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue :-( If you get to a solution, please share.

Comment: Yea -- still working on it. I created a new project to test and it works from there as intended... Solution will be posted if/when found.

Comment: As long as its using the layouts: application: lookup it gives the same error.  I found a work-around if I copy application.html.erb to another file and use the new filename under the layouts: hierarchy in the en.yml, then it works.  Not sure why this is happening since I have no issues if I start a new project from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: Been away from this project for some time but figured out the issue....

SOLVED: Pretty stupid I might add.
**Make sure you do not tab ('\t') to space the text in the files.**
Clearly it's not able to compile correctly with the tab characters.

Comment: Fun note:  The tabbing vs spacing debate from the show Silicon Valley plays in nicely here!

Answer (score 0):

I run today into the exact same problem and after a debugging session I found the root of the problem. I bet this is your problem too, because it also makes sense with your workaround and with the issue not happening on a brand new project. Do you happen to have the hierarchy

```
en:
  layouts:
    application:
```

defined somewhere else in your `yml` files?

I was defining

```
en:
  layouts:
    header:
      language: "Language"
```

and

```
en:
  layouts:
    header:
      my_profile: "My profile"
```

in two different places, so I guess the translator would look for the first (and assumed unique) occurrence of the key combination and would never find the other one...

Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: Checked. No, I did not have it defined anywhere else, but thx.

Comment: Sure! Glad you sorted that out

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else:

My issue was a little different — I was including periods in the translation keys (e.g., `In retrospect...: 'In retrospect, it should've been obvious that was a bad idea.'`). Enclosing the keys in single quotes did not make a difference, so I just removed the periods entirely, and the problem was solved.